# Query optimization needed because of too many sub queries and sub query dependency in where conditions

Tags: mysql

I'm writing code for the production report.
I had written this query

```
SELECT
    P.*,
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(id) AS cnt
    FROM
        bales
    WHERE
        create_date < '2019-11-01' AND product_id = P.id AND(TYPE = 'bale' OR TYPE = 'bag')
) AS before_prod,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(id) AS cnt
    FROM
        bales
    WHERE
        (
            dispatched = '0' OR disp_bunch = '0'
        ) AND dispatch_date < '2019-11-01' AND product_id = P.id AND(TYPE = 'bale' OR TYPE = 'bag')
) AS before_dispatched,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(id) AS cnt
    FROM
        bales
    WHERE
        create_date BETWEEN '2019-11-01' AND '2019-11-06' AND product_id = P.id AND(TYPE = 'bale' OR TYPE = 'bag')
) AS production,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(id) AS cnt
    FROM
        bales
    WHERE
        (
            dispatched = '0' OR disp_bunch = '0'
        ) AND dispatch_date BETWEEN '2019-11-01' AND '2019-11-06' AND product_id = P.id AND(TYPE = 'bale' OR TYPE = 'bag')
) AS production_dispatched,
C.name AS category_name
FROM
    products P
INNER JOIN category C ON
    C.id = P.category
```

This query is working but as I have too many records in all tables it takes too much time.
also, I need only records where **before_prod, before_dispatched, production, production_dispatched** all these subquery results should be greater than 0.

I tried to use **having** clause but it also takes too much time.

I have also tried php for loop, * LOGIC: first all products than in for loop its production. but it was much slower.*

How can I optimize my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join` instead and `select case` to sum your data that matches your conditions.

```
select p.*, t.*
from products p
inner join (
    select t2.id, sum(case when create_date < '2019-11-01' then 1 else 0 end) as before_prod
        , sum(case when (dispatched = '0' or disp_bunch = '0') and  create_date < '2019-11-01' then 1 else 0 end) as before_dispatched
        , sum(case when create_date between '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-06' then 1 else 0 end) as production
        , sum(case when (dispatched = '0' or disp_bunch = '0') and create_date between '2019-11-01' and '2019-11-06' then 1 else 0 end) as production_dispatched
    from bales t1
    inner join product t2 on t2.id= t1.product_id 
    inner join category t3 on t3.id = t2.category
    where t1.TYPE in ('bale', 'bag')
    group by t2.id) t
on t.id = p.id
```

Comment: production and production_dispatched are always being 0 as per this query.

Comment: two error found 1. in where and, 2. Unknown column  p.id and group by p.id .